# Parsing multiple lines in config file divided by + sign in Python

Tags: python, parsing, configuration

I have config file like:

```
[Default]
Mykey=123,456,789
+234,567,891
+345,678,912
```

Can you give me suggestions how to parse them using ConfigParser ( python )
so I can have these values in array or list for example:

```
import configparser
conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf.read(r"c:\tmp\myini.ini")
```

after that I want to have these lines parased like

```
conf["Default"]["Mykey"] --> returns array/list with parsed values
```

**Result should be like:**

```
print(conf["Default"]["MyKey"])
['123,456,789','234,567,891','345,678,912']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your ini file format to

```
[Default]
Mykey:['123,456,789', '+234,567,891', '+345,678,912']
```

After this you can access it like

```
print conf["Default"]["Mykey"]
```

**Result**:

```
['123,456,789', '+234,567,891', '+345,678,912']
```

Comment: this not works for me. I cannot edit my config.ini because it is used from other app in this way. I just want it is to parse it like:

`print conf["Default"]["Mykey"]`

Result:
`['123,456,789','234,567,891','345,678,912']`